# Recovering an Ehresmann connection from its parallel transport

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

How can we recover an Ehresmann connection on a general fiber bundle (as a horizontal distribution) knowing only its induced parallel transport?

Answer (score 1):

This is the type of question that I like, but hope I got it correct as short it is formulated. The answer should be directly over here and particularly see references over there [>>>here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport#Recovering_the_connection_from_the_parallel_transport)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However this seems to be limited to vector bundles whereas I am interested in arbitrary general fiber bundles.

Comment: Got it. This is however a very exotic generalisation. Let me be back if I find something.